# Circular Dependency in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I am trying to create the equivalent of a check register in Google Sheets for a joint account. The goal is to keep track of how much each person has in the account based on credits and debits, as well as an overall balance.

The columns I have set up are

- A: Date,
- B: Description,
- C: Debit (person 1),
- D: Credit (person 1),
- E: Balance (person 1),
- F: Debit (person 2),
- G: Credit (person 2),
- H: Balance (person 2),
- and I: Balance (overall).

Where I am running into trouble is the formula for calculating the individual balances. The way I had it set up in Excel was to use a formula like this:

(In row H3)

```
=H2-F3+G3
```

So this would take the balance of the person from row 2, add any credits and subtract any debits for Row 3, and insert that value into Cell H3. I have it set up to automatically copy the formula to each new row that is added, so I don't have to do it manually every time there is a new transaction.

The formula I currently have in that cell H3 in Google Sheets is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H2:H-F3:F+G3:G)
```

Cell H2 has a static value, as it is my starting point for that column. The above formula is giving me a circular dependency error, and I cannot figure out why; I don't believe it is referencing cell H3 at all, but I just started working with Google Sheets, so maybe my understanding of the arrayformula is incorrect.

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I've never used the ARRAYFORMULA function, but I believe the problem is the fact that your formula exists in the H column, but references the entire column H in what it is trying to compute (the H2:H part signifies that it acts on the whole column, but since the result is also stored in column H, it becomes a circular dependency).

It's perhaps not a great solution, but you could go back to the formula you had:

```
=H2-F3+G3
```

and simply 'drag' that formula all the way down your column.

If you have your heart set on the ARRAYFORMULA function, you'll have to store the result in a column other than one of the 3 used in the formula (G,F,H).

Comment: I would just use the formula I already have, but since there is no set amount of rows I will be working with, I want it to add the formula to the next row automatically when it is inserted.

I guess I could just use a separate column with the same formula and reference that one, then just hide that column.

Comment: Have you looked at App Scripts at all? You may be able to do something with the onEdit or onChange spreadsheet triggers, that could look to see if values are present in (for example) G3 and F3 but H3 is empty, then it could automatically add the appropriate formula into the cell: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder

Answer (score 0):

Paste this formula in H3:

```
=ArrayFormula( SUMIF(ROW(F3:F),"<="&ROW(F3:F),G3:G)
              -SUMIF(ROW(F3:F),"<="&ROW(F3:F),F3:F)
              +H2)
```

The answer is about finding cumulative sum with ArrayFormula. Here's Adam's (@AdamL) [sulution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46100/118810).